# Create array of arrays with varying sizes

Tags: arrays, arduino

I'm working on an Arduino project which requires an array of arrays, each with varying sizes. Here are the arrays:

```
int seg0[6] = {10, 3, 4, 5, 12, 11};
int seg1[2] = {3, 4};
int seg2[5] = {10, 11, 2, 4, 5};
int seg3[5] = {10, 11, 2, 12, 5};
int seg4[4] = {3, 11, 2, 12};
int seg5[5] = {10, 3, 2, 12, 5};
int seg6[6] = {10, 3, 2, 4, 5, 12};
int seg7[3] = {10, 11, 12};
int seg8[7] = {10, 11, 12, 5, 4, 3, 2};
int seg9[6] = {10, 3, 11, 2, 12, 5};
```

I'd like to have them all in one big array, so that I can enter a number, eg. 8, and then it would give me the array with the index number which was specified (`array[0]` would give `seg0`, `array[8]` would give `seg8`, etc).

Anyone have any tips?
Thanks

Comment: Is it C or Obj-C? AFAIK these are pretty different languages

Comment: C, sorry about that, always thought they were the same.

Comment: @JoH1 It's Arduino as stated. definitively not C, and not exactly C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are asking about dimension array

```
int seg0[6] = {10, 3, 4, 5, 12, 11};
int seg1[2] = {3, 4};
int seg2[5] = {10, 11, 2, 4, 5};
int seg3[5] = {10, 11, 2, 12, 5};
int seg4[4] = {3, 11, 2, 12};
int seg5[5] = {10, 3, 2, 12, 5};
int seg6[6] = {10, 3, 2, 4, 5, 12};
int seg7[3] = {10, 11, 12};
int seg8[7] = {10, 11, 12, 5, 4, 3, 2};
int seg9[6] = {10, 3, 11, 2, 12, 5};

// Keep all of seg in a dimension array
int* dimention_array[10] = {seg0, seg1, seg2, seg3, seg4, seg5, seg6, seg7, seg8, seg9};

// Print first element of |seg0|
printf("%d", dimention_array[0][0]);
```

Comment: That's right, but I think you should also store the dimensions somewhere, not only the pointers.

Comment: @Bob__ Maybe, it's up to OP's purpose.